# Use image batch for multiple runs in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I´m trying to implement an input pipeline in TensorFlow which holds the input batch for multiple runs of the graph due to multiple weight updates in different network parts.

I thought that i could wrap the input pipeline with a condition:

```
# flag to skip image fetch 
forwarding_network = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [], name='forwarding_network')

input_images = None # image queue from input pipeline, must be set in real
input_labels = None # label queue from input pipeline, must be set in real

INPUT_HEIGHT = 64 # Height of the images/labels
WIDTH_HEIGHT = 64 # Width of the images/labels

# Fetch new batch from input pipeline
def forwardIR():
    image_batch_fetch, label_batch_fetch = tf.train.batch([input_images, input_labels], \
                                                          batchsize=32, capacity=64)

    with tf.variable_scope('im_reader_forward'):
        image_batch = tf.get_variable("image_batch ", shape=[32, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH, 3], \
                      dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False, \
                      initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

        image_batch = tf.assign(image_batch, image_batch_fetch)

        label_batch = tf.get_variable("label_batch ", shape=[32, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH, 1], \
                      dtype=tf.uint8, trainable=False, \
                      initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

        label_batch = tf.assign(label_batch, label_batch_fetch)
    return image_batch, label_batch

# Hold last batch, no new fetch from pipeline
def holdIR():
    with tf.variable_scope('im_reader_forward', reuse=True):
        return tf.get_variable('image_batch', dtype=tf.float32), \
               tf.get_variable('label_batch', dtype=tf.uint8)

# Switch: If forwarding_network == True, fetch new images from queue; else not)
image_batch, label_batch = tf.cond(forwarding_network, lambda: forwardIR(), lambda: holdIR())

# calculate loss with batch
net = Model(image_batch)
loss = net.predict()
```

My problem is, that the training starts without any error or failure but nothing happens. Maybe there is no connection between the variables and the network operations? The output from the condition is directly fed into the network model.

Comment: Hello Toxiin, and welcome to [SO]! Do you think it would be possible to make the code more minimalistic (less code) with more comments (you can read more about making an [MCVE here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? Also It'd be awesome if it was runnable for reproducability. It's really hard to read all that code and really get into what is going on!

Comment: A typical input pipeline in tensorflow would yield tensors, not variables. Variables in tensorflow are used when there is state that you want to update: for example, for parameters to the model whose weights need to be updated as the model is trained. The input pipeline should yield your training data, which, while heterogenous, shouldn't be updated as the model is training.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, its much easier than i thought. -.- :D

Solved it by evaluating the part for the images/labels fetching by running it a tf session first and give the output via placeholders into the training iterations.

```
## define input pipeline, network, loss calculation, session, ...

image_batch_out, label_batch_out = sess.run([image_batch_ir, label_batch_ir])

feed_dict = { image_batch : image_batch_out, label_batch : label_batch_out }

loss_1, _ = sess.run([loss_val_1, train_op_1], feed_dict=feed_dict)
loss_2, _ = sess.run([loss_val_2, train_op_2], feed_dict=feed_dict)
loss_3, _ = sess.run([loss_val_3, train_op_3], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

No variables needed at all as has been mentioned in the comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

To add on to your answer, you can directly feed the `image_batch_ir` and `label_batch_ir` tensors to the ops that use the placeholders as input. 
For example, if your old code was:

```
image_batch_ir, label_batch_ir = ...
image_batch = tf.placeholder(...)
label_batch = tf.placeholder(...)
loss_val = some_ops(image_batch, label_batch)
image_batch_out, label_batch_out = sess.run([image_batch_ir, label_batch_ir])

feed_dict = { image_batch : image_batch_out, label_batch : label_batch_out }

loss = sess.run([loss_val], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

You can instead do:

```
image_batch_ir, label_batch_ir = ...
loss_val = some_ops(image_batch_ir, label_batch_ir)
loss = sess.run([loss_val], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```